# генотоксическая примесь vs. генотоксичная примесь

Tags: выбор-слов, переводы

Читаю текст, в котором описывается исследование лекарственного средства на наличие "potential genotoxic impurities". Задумался - как это было бы по-русски:

1. Потенциально **генотоксические** примеси
2. Потенциально **генотоксичные** примеси

Может быть, оба варианта равнозначны и пригодны к употреблению?

P.S. [Из словаря паронимов](http://www.classes.ru/grammar/122.Vishnyakova/18-t/html/topic_10.html) (О.В. Вишнякова):

> ТОКСИЧЕСКИЙ (спец.). 1. Ядовитый, отравляющий, являющийся токсином. 2. Обусловленный дей­ствием токсинов.
>   Токсическ|ий: 1) ~ое действие, поражение, оружие; ~ий продукт; 2) ~ий гепатит, бронхит. О В первые 9 недель беременности назначать хлоридин нельзя во избежание его токсического действия на плод. (М.Машковский. Лекарственные средства.)   В шесть часов  вечера в больницу поступил больной  с токсическим гепатитом.
>
> ТОКСИЧНЫЙ. Способный вызвать отравление. Токсичн|ый: ~ая прослойка; ~ое лекарство; ~ые выделения.
>   Опавшие листья не могут образовывать токсичную подстилку для растений. (В.Галузинская. Аллелопатия- наука о
>   взаимоотношениях растений)
>   Из числа наиболее токсичных минералов следует особо выделить соединения мышьяка,
>   сурьмы, меди, ртути, свинца. (Д. Григорьев. Коварные минералы.)
>   Сравните: токсическое вещество — вещество, которое может отравить; токсичное вещество — вещество, которое состоит из яда.

Comment: Да, конечно; я уберу напоминание тогда :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно Англо-русскому биологическому словарю "**genotoxic**" переводится как **генотоксический**. (*Чибисова О.И., Смирнов Н.Н.. Новый Русско-Английский биологический словарь. New Russian-English biological dictionary. 2003*)

Такой же перевод встречается в медицинском словаре [Англо-русский медицинский словарь / Под ред. И.Ю. Марковиной, Э.Г. Улумбекова. 2013. - 496 с.](http://vmede.org/sait/?page=8&id=Anglo_rus_slovar_markovina_2013&menu=Anglo_rus_slovar_markovina_2013)

В то же время, в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) прилагательное от слова генотоксичность - генотоксичный, и на сайте academic.ru у слова "генотоксический" нет толкования, а у слова "генотоксичный" - [есть](http://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&stype=0) (со ссылкой на справочник технического переводчика и с тем же переводом "genotoxic").

Исходя из этого, могу предположить, что сейчас норма ещё не установилась и **допустимы оба варианта**, но лучше написать "**генотоксичный**".